# Android AppCompat theme issues when upgrading RN version

Tags: android, react-native

I am attempting to upgrade my react-native version to 0.59.10. My app crashes upon attempt to debug and I get this error when running `adb logcat`.

````
E/AndroidRuntime( 9402): Process: com.attendance, PID: 9402
E/AndroidRuntime( 9402): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.attendance/com.attendance.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }```

This is my current style code:
````

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I can get the app to run by simply changing android:theme to 
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
but the theme is not the same as before.

I have tried implementing all the properties in the initial error but then the app never loads.

Any ideas on how to get my app to load and have the original themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified styles to:

````
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>

    </style>

</resources>```
and this resolved the issue.
````